# Cannot successfully delete record from the database

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, entity-framework, typescript

Am I doing something wrong? Everything seems to be OK, but the record doesn't get deleted from the database:

C#

```
    @{
    WebSecurity.RequireAuthenticatedUser();

    myModel.OSFEntities database = new myModel.OSFEntities();

    var productInformation = Request["Pi"];

    int productId = Convert.ToInt32(productInformation.Substring(0, productInformation.LastIndexOf("-")));
    string productType = productInformation.Substring(productInformation.LastIndexOf("-", productInformation.Length)).Replace("-", String.Empty);
    var userId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
    DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    int quantity = 1;
    string quoteId = "";

    if (Request["Action"] == "Remove")
    {
        if (Session["QuoteId"] != null)
        {
            quoteId = (String)Session["QuoteId"];

            myModel.Quote quotes = database.Quotes.FirstOrDefault(
                q => q.UserId == userId && q.QuoteId == quoteId && q.ProductId == productId && q.ProductType == productType);

            database.Quotes.DeleteObject(quotes);
            database.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

TypeScript:

```
function RemoveProductFromCart(e) {
    // Remove from their Cart.
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                // The data is now stored in the responseText.
                // Change value in textbox to 0 so user knows it's been
                // removed from their cart.
                var el = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(e.id + "-TB");
                if (el != null) {
                    el.value = "0";
                }
            }

            else {
                // Server responded with a different response code.
                alert(xhr.statusText);
            }

        }
    }

    var parameters = "Pi=" + encodeURIComponent(e.id) + "&" + "Action=Remove";

    xhr.open("POST", "../Cart.cshtml");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length.toString());
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xhr.send(parameters);

    return e.id;
}
```

While debugging with <kbd>F12</kbd> Dev Tools, I see:

[image]

... which leads me to believe that it's something wrong with my C# code. Why won't it delete from the database?

Comment: I would **strongly** advise you get all that business logic out of your view and into *at least* the controller...

Comment: This is WebPages **not MVC**. And yes, I have separated everything as much as humanly possible.

Comment: Sorry the code above looked suspiciously like MVC syntax. Have you verified that your query for the quote is actually returning something & not null?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks @JohnSaunders: I got used to adding as much info about what I'm using in my title since a lot of people have trouble reading the actual question, and its tags.

Comment: I have been here over 3 years and have not seen people have trouble using tags. And if they won't read your question, then they won't be of much help.

Comment: When you debug this, can you verify the values of userId, quoteId, productId, and productType are what you expect?   And that quotes is returning and object and not "default"

Comment: Thanks guys, I just double checked that the values I'm getting back are as expected. The quotes is returning normal too. When I output the values of quotes, all the values are also the correct ones.

Comment: Have you tried putting the code in that innermost `if{ }` block into a `try{ } catch(){ }`, just in case there is an error being swallowed somewhere along the way (I don't know the structure around that code snippet to know whether that's plausible or not)?  The other thing that comes to mind is that you might have relationships defined in your database that are preventing the deletion from being successful.  That doesn't seem all that likely either, just a thought since your code looks alright to me.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that. Didn't throw any exceptions.

Comment: Does this quote have any child relations? or any entities that reference this quote?  If any exist, they need to be deleted first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few suggestions.

In these cases it is always fairly likely that one of the request items isn't exactly what you thought it was, so either the action or the quote id could contain a surprise. You could check those using a breakpoint.

The next item to check is that `myModel.Quote quotes` contains the matched quote object. Perhaps one of the filters you have there is ruling it out even though the id is correct (for example it isn't linked to the current user, or the product type is different etc).

I notice you are using...

```
database.Quotes.DeleteObject(quotes);
database.SaveChanges();
```

i.e. you use `Quotes` on the first, not on the second: Should the `SaveChanges` and `DeleteObject` calls not be placed against the same context?

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah that does make a lot of sense. I originally ready an article about saving changes in the DB and this is how their code was, and it's always worked so I didn't really see anything wrong with it.

You were right though, about the surprise. After setting a breakpoint (which for some reason I forgot you could do that) There was a leading space before the quantity. I'm also surprised there weren't any exceptions thrown. Thank you Sohnee. :)